# New instance of an object referenced by an interface in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

I am working on a **JDK6 project**.

I have a pojo like:

```java
public class MyPojo implements serializable {
  private List<Integer> ids;

  public List<Integers> getIds() {
    return ids;
  }

  public List<Integers> setIds(List<Integer> ids) {
    // idsCopy = copy of ids; // how can I do it?
    this.ids = idsCopy;
  }
}
```

I'd like to store a copy of the parameter `ids` passed in the setter, but I don't want to specialize it in the `setId` method signature by declaring the reference as a particular implementation of the List interface: depending on where the pojo is used, `ids` could be either a LinkedList, or an ArrayList, etc.

I'd like to keep the same implementation of the `ids` parameter.

How can I do the copy?

The first thing I thought was: `ids.getClass().newInstance()`, but it needs to be surrounded by a try/catch block for InstantiationException and IllegalAccessException, in particular because I am not sure that the actual implementation of `ids` has an empty constructor. Is there something more immediate?

---

**Update**
In this case the most common, straightforward and reasonable thing to do is avoiding making a copy and let who will use the class MyPojo passing a copy of the object to set, for instance:

```java
List<Integer> ls = new Arraylist<>();
MyPojo pj = new MyPojo();
pj.setIds(ls.clone()); // or using copy constructor or anything else..
```

At the beginning I had the idea to do like this:

```java
public <T extends List<Integer> & Cloneable> void setIds(T ids) {
  this.ids = ids.clone();
}
```

enforcing using a class implementing also Cloneable but the javadoc of Cloneable interface explains very good why this is not intended to work (and also why reflection on clone would not too):

> A class implements the `Cloneable` interface to
>   indicate to the method that it
>   is legal for that method to make a
>   field-for-field copy of instances of that class.
>
> Invoking Object's clone method on an instance that does not implement the
>   `Cloneable` interface results in the exception
>   `CloneNotSupportedException` being thrown.
>
> By convention, classes that implement this interface should override
>   Object.clone (which is protected) with a public method.
>   See for details on overriding this
>   method.
>
> Note that this interface does *not* contain the clone method.
>   Therefore, it is not possible to clone an object merely by virtue of the
>   fact that it implements this interface.  Even if the clone method is invoked
>   reflectively, there is no guarantee that it will succeed.

---

At the end, regardless the context, the answer to my question

> Is there something more immediate?

is "no", most probably because there should not be the need to do it...
..even though..

#### https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Vulnerability/RSPEC-2384

Comment: If you want to keep the same implementation, you have to go the reflection route. But ... The real questions is: _Why do you want to keep the same implementation?_ Usually, there is no need to do so!

Comment: The direct way to do that is clone(). But some implementations of List don't allow it. Sometimes it's just impossible (or at least, made way too complicated to be sane) to have a copy of the same implementation.

Comment: You've got to sit down and think why you think you need this. Does your logic depend on the implementation? Does something else depend on getting the same type back as was passed in the setter?

Comment: Just as a side note, but as *ids* tend to be unique I suggest using a `Set` or even a `SortedSet` if the order matters

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose One could use a LinkedList because they care about the constant time while performing some operations with the iterator, someone else instead, in some other part of the project, could use an ArrayList because they need index access (with get) in constant time. I don't want to enforce an implementation, moreover in an hidden way.

Comment: Of course in the context of a Pojo: the `ids` field is not going to be used inside this class but it will be gotten and used by some other class, thus, if it is set passing a LinkedList, I'd like that a linked list will be returned as well.

Comment: Why - then - do you want to copy at all? Keep in mind that you have a getter for the list, so copying/cloning is useless in the setter.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose squid:S2384 of Sonar requires a copy when getting/setting a mutable object, but in this  particular case I want to be sure that any action performed on the original list in the same scope when the setter is called does not lead to any change in the list stored in MyPojo

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something more immediate?

There are two possible ways to do this:

- The method you proposed: use reflection to invoke the no-args constructor create a new empty list, and then use `List::addAll` to copy the elements to the new list.
- Use the `Object::clone` method to create the copy.

Either approach (if it works!) will create a list object of the same type as the original.  But neither method is guaranteed to work for all possible `List` classes.

- The reflective approach fails if the list implementation class has no usable / accessible no-args constructor.
- The `clone` approach fails if the list implementation class doesn't override `Object::clone` appropriately.

Note that these are not hypothetical concerns.  A list implementation class may be deliberately designed to prevent programs making clones of the list.  For example, there may be some relationship between the list and (say) a database query result set, such that cloning makes no sense.

But the flip-side is that if the library designer didn't provide a no-args constructor or a `clone` override, they *probably* did it for a good reason.

---

Finally, it is questionable that you should be *trying* to do this at all.  There is no obvious reason for your `MyPojo` classes `ids` property to use the same `List` class as the original argument.  This is actually making the behavior `MyPojo` class dependent on the behavior of the supplied list.  I would argue that this is a *bad thing* because you are weakening the abstraction boundary for your `MyPojo` class.

Comment: MyPojo would not be dependent on the implementation of `ids`. If `ids` is declared with a List reference then everything that is not exposed by that interface is not used/needed in the class MyPojo. Moreover, in general, to me, a behavior like the one that follows is bad (even if I would never use isinstance in any part of the project): 
`List<Integer> ls = new LinkedList<Integer>(); 
MyPojo pojo = new MyPojo(); 
pojo.setIds(ls); 
pojo.getIds() instanceof LinkedList; //false
`. (It would happen if storing ids in an ArrayList for instance)

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I am saying.  If you consider the `ids` as part of the `MyPojo` abstraction, then the behavior of the actual type of the list's value should be considered as part of the behavior of a given `MyPojo`.  What if I "set" an immutable list, or a list with some funky properties?

Comment: Ok, I guess I got your point, correct me if I am wrong: if there is a situation where a LinkedList is needed and another different one where an ArrayList is preferred instead, then there should be two different MyPojo classes (or something like MyPojo<L extends List> with reference of `ids` of type L instead of List).

Comment: Hypothetically, yes.  However, I would be very surprised if a real domain object had this particular requirement.

Comment: And if you really have such a requirement, better approach would be for the `get` operation to store the list given to it.  Let the caller make the copy if it wants / needs to.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said it yourself:

> The first thing I thought was: ids.getClass().newInstance(), but it
>   needs to be surrounded by a try/catch block for InstantiationException
>   and IllegalAccessException, in particular because **I am not sure that
>   the actual implementation of ids has an empty constructor**. Is there
>   something more immediate?

How will you be able to *construct* an instance of the underlying class when you don't even know what the constructor looks like? Say through reflection, you know what *a* (there could be more than one) constructor looks like, you still have to worry about things like:

- **Private vs Internal/Package-Private vs Public** - How do you handle each case? Some implementations of `List` such as the ones found in the guava library use the builder pattern to construct the collection and therefore make the constructor private.
- **Number of constructor arguments** - If more than one, how do you construct the rest?
- **Exceptions thrown by the constructor** - How do you catch them all? Don't say "catch `Exception`" because you may miss `Throwable`.
- **Multiple constructors** - How do you decide which one to call?
- **Many more corner cases to deal with...**

---

You should adopt the KISS (**K**eep **I**t **S**imple **S**oldier) principle as well as the SoC (**S**eparation **o**f **C**oncerns) principle. Keep it simple and you will be rewarded. Let the person using the Pojo decide how they want to retrieve the list. As long as you make it clear (through documentation) what the method does, it is up to the user to make rational decisions as to how they use that method.

If they do something like:

```
LinkedList<Integer> myIds = ...;
myPojo.setIds(myIds);
```

then let them decide how to retrieve the `ids`; They can either cast the returned type or make a copy.

If you made it clear in the documentation that the list is copied, then the person using this POJO should know to make a copy as a `LinkedList` when they retrieve it, otherwise it should be safe for them to cast the list to a `LinkedList`.

---

I would still argue that even the above is not simple enough. The simplest thing to do (and this is what is widely accepted) is to use the most general type for the work needed. If you need a Mapping type, use `Map`, not `HashMap` or `List/Set` of tuples; If you need a unique collection, use `Set`, if you need a general collection, use `List`, etc.

Comment: Yes I agree that in this case the copy should not be made internally but let all the control on that to whom is using the setter

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Arrays.asList` for that e.g.

```
public void setIds(List<Integer> ids) {
    this.ids = Arrays.asList(ids.toArray(new Integer[ids.size()]));
}
```

this should work for Java 1.6

Comment: Well ... OP explicitely said that he wants to keep the list implementation class of the argument.